# How to use Laravel-DomPDF and Laravel-Snappy at same time

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have using Laravel-dompdf in my laravel project, then i install laravel-snappy to generate one because dompdf can't handle it, in documentation it has same name facade's, so it could be better to manually register the Facade. When i use laravel-snappy, it make isPHPEnabled option dompdf not exist.

How to use laravel-dompdf with larave-snappy installed?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem. waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable auto discovery for snappy in composer.json like this

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
         "dont-discover": [
             "barryvdh/laravel-snappy"
          ]
     }
 },
```

then just register custom facade in config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
    ...
    'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,
    'SnappyPDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
 ];
```